# How to say "many" in "There are many wheat fields" in Japanese? (たくさん or いっぱい?)

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

I am writing a short descriptive text and I would like to write "There are many wheat fields". Is it better to say 「たくさんの麦畑があります。」or 「麦畑がいっぱいあります。」?

Comment: これちょっとくらい参考になります？https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38329/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentences both sound fine.

Using たくさん or いっぱい, you can say...

> - 麦畑が**たくさん**あります。
> - 麦畑が**いっぱい**あります。<sub>(いっぱい in this sense sounds more casual/colloquial than たくさん)</sub>
> - **たくさんの**麦畑があります。<sub>(often used in writing or formal speech -- though 多くの, 多数の etc. would be more formal)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

in answer to ur question 麦畑が多い